How to put animation correctly from one character into another in Unreal Engine 5 using retargeting? Root problem
So I imported animation from Maximo into Unreal Engine 5 but my character is not moving properly in running slide animation. I used retarget Root option and now my character's animation is good but I had to retarget Root on character pelvis to make it work. Right now the problem is that when character is finished with slide animation he is going back to his root position while I want him to stay on the place where animation is over. Here are the pictures to make it easier for you:


